# File reading slows down after reading multiple files - PYTHON

Tags: python, file

I am currently using python for some data analysis and for some reason the file reading process slows down after multiple files are read. The following is my code:

The function that reads the file

```
import numpy as np
import numba 

def read_data(f,read):
    nskip = 9
    for i in range(nskip):           ##skip these lines
        line = f.readline()
        if i==3:
            n = int(line.split()[0])  #how many particles 
            types = np.zeros(n)
            pos = np.zeros((n,2))
            ang = np.zeros((n))
    for i in range(n):
        line = f.readline()
        if read:
            types[i] = int(line.split()[0])  #particle data
            pos[i,0] = float(line.split()[2])
            pos[i,1] = float(line.split()[3])
            ang[i] = float(line.split()[5])
    return types,pos,ang
```

The following is the loop that works on the data

```
eta_list = [0.03 ,0.0625 ,0.125 ,0.25 ,0.5 ,1.0 ,2.0 ,4.0 ,8.0 ,16.0, 32.0, 64.0]
files = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
chi = 1.25
Nskip = 5500
Ntotal = 6000
N_surv = []
for eta in eta_list:   #loop over parameter eta
    num_surv = 0
    num = 0
    for fnum in files:    #each parameter has 20 files
        fname = '../all_test_eta{}_chi{}_{}.lammpstrj'.format(eta,chi,fnum)
        f = open(fname,mode='r')
        for i in tqdm(range(Nskip)):     #TQDM to time the read_data call
            _,_,_ = read_data(f,read=0)   #skip these frames -- equilibriation 
        for i in range(Ntotal-Nskip):
            a,b,c = read_data(f,read=1)   #work on this data 
            num_surv += np.sum(a==3)
            num+=1
        f.close()
    num_surv = num_surv /(len(files)*num)
    N_surv.append(num_surv)
```

Now the tqdm function is timing my loop and the first 20 (or so) reads are fast - 45k it/s
but suddenly the reading slows down to only 600it/s
I cant seem to understand why this happens, any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: the file sizes are approximately the same.

Comment: is possible you are out of memory and the data is going to swap?

Comment: I think it does use swap memory at some point (psutil.swap_memory shows an increase from 0.2% to 3% usage as each file is read, not sure if this is significant), to me it seems like the memory is not being freed after each loop.